# WLAN connecting to Modem/Router but not to internet beyond

Tags: internet-connection

PROBLEM : Laptop connecting to modem, but unable to connect to internet through WLAN - whereas it works fine through Ethernet LAN.

DETAILS :
I changed my old DSL modem (provided by the local service providers -BSNL) which was a 150 Mhz to a new one of 300 Mhz. The old modem was ITI Make Model DNA-A211-1 and the new one is D-Link 2750U.

My IBM-Win XP desktop (connected through ethernet cable), Toshiba Tablet-Android and HP-Windows Vista laptop (both through WLAN) connects seamlessly to this modem and the internet beyond. Modem is also set for 16 users.

However, I have problems with my Compaq laptop (Model C769US) - using Windows Vista. While it connects perfectly to the internet if I use the ethernet cable, it is not able to connect to the internet through the WLAN (however, it does connect to the Modem). The WLAN device in the laptop is Atheros AR5007.

I have tried resetting the WLAN hardware, deleted the driver and re-installed, updated the driver, reset the settings, checked whether IP/DNS is set for automatic discovery, unchecked ipv6, etc, etc - all to no avail.

I then tried it back with the old Modem and it worked fine - which shows that nothing wrong with the Compaq laptop.

Since all other equipment are working with the new modem, it does not look like I need to fiddle with the modem.

I even shut down all other machines and put ONLY the Compaq on the new modem (in case it had a hidden limitation on number of devices) - but still it did not work.

I'm baffled ! !

Pls help.

Answer (score 0):

MTNL/BSNL are not serious about their Internet services.

I suggest you call BSNL and request them to configure your new device. Make sure that they haven't set any kind of limitations. You may also try custom Firmware for your device if available such as [DD-WRT](http://www.dd-wrt.com/site/support/router-database) at your own risk.